# jQuery html() removes element instead of setting contents

Tags: jquery, dom

I am working on a small website, partially powered by AJAX. For one part of it, when the user clicks a button, content is loaded into an element. The issue is that, rather than inserting the HTML into the element, the element (#user .padded) is removed entirely! However, running from the console (Chrome) it works just fine.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var attr = $(this).attr('data-id');

if (!$('#user').is(':visible')) {
    $('#user').slideDown(300);
}
var user = $('#user');

$.ajax({
    url: window.baseurl + "/admin/users/" + attr + "/get",
    timeout: 5000,
    cache: false
}).success(function(response) {
    $('#user .padded').html(response);
}).fail(function() {
    $('#user .padded').html('<div class="alert">Unable to load the user, we\'re sorry!</div>');
}).always(function() {
    spinner.stop();
});
```

Yes, I do realize it is not very efficient at the moment, but I've simplified it for debugging. In this case, it is only the fail() function which is called, as the sever-side has not yet been implemented. No Javascript errors are reported, just a 404.

I read something about html() clearing certain states, so I also tried with just show() instead of slideDown(300). No luck there either.

Any ideas on what would be causing this?
Before:
[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: `.html` will erase everything inside the element you are selecting and then insert the contents you pass as a parameter. If you want to append the contents see `appendTo` function.

Comment: I've added before and after pictures above. It doesn't replace the contents - that's what I want it to do - it removes the whole element.

Comment: Show us the code for the `spinner.stop` too, please?

Comment: It's from spin.js (http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/misc/spin.js/index.html). Commenting it out does not affect the problem.

Comment: Ah, found it! It was in the *instantiation* of spin.js - removing the script caused it to work. Now to find out how to fix that... Thanks for your advice(s)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you ended up with the `padded` element being removed entirely, see my test below based on your code and assuming the structure of the HTML ...

Based on the following HTML:

```
<div id="user">
    User element
    <div class="padded">Padded</div>
</div>
```

And applying the following jQuery:

```
$('#user .padded').html('<div class="alert">Unable to load the user, we\'re sorry!</div>');
```

The DOM is manipulated as follows:

```
<div id="user">
    User element
    <div class="padded"><div class="alert">Unable to load the user, we're sorry!</div></div>
</div>
```

Perhaps you're removing the node in some other way? Use the Chrome (or Firebug) dom inspector to see what it did with the HTML.

Comment: I've added before and after pictures above.